# I cannot identify what is causing this unexpected upload error on my app

Tags: android, file-upload, android-volley

I am relatively new to android development and I have been squeezing my brain juice for hours on probably a very simple error. Look, the app's been working fine yesterday and after I made some changes on some XML files and ran the app on my emulator, I experience this error:

```
2019-09-10 14:13:19.533 6388- 
6516/ E/Volley: [301] 
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 406 for 
http://applybpojobs.com/widevalueappfiles/server/api/addvehicle.php
2019-09-10 14:13:21.573 1633-1656/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load 
memtrack module
```

I have already tried numerous solutions on the web and it seems not to fix my problem. This is my code:

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
    URL_ADD_VEHICLE,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.i(TAG, response.toString());
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String Success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                        if (Success.equals("1")){
                            hideLoader();
                            Toast.makeText(Addvehicle.this,"Vehicle Added 
     Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }else if (Success.equals("0")){
                            hideLoader();
                            Toast.makeText(Addvehicle.this,"Vehicle 
     Already Exist",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        hideLoader();
                        Toast.makeText(Addvehicle.this,"Vehicle Added 
     Error"+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    Toast.makeText(Addvehicle.this,"Vehicle Added 
     Error"+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    hideLoader();
                }


            })
```

I am receiving a blank response from this URL and I need guidance on how to fix this:

http://*********.php

For whatever reasons, this page on my app stopped working because of this error. Any help would be appreciated. Again, I'm basically new in android development so please understand that a simple error like this bleeds my nose.

Here are my server php codes:

```
<?php

require '../core/connect.php';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {


    $plate_number=$_POST['plate_number'];
    $vin=$_POST['vin'];
    $car_make=$_POST['car_make'];
    $car_model=$_POST['car_model'];
    $car_year=$_POST['car_year'];
    $displacement=$_POST['displacement'];
    $fuel_type=$_POST['fuel_type'];
    $transmission=$_POST['transmission'];
    $mileage=$_POST['mileage'];
    $owner_name=$_POST['owner_name'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $phone_number=$_POST['phone_number'];
    $email_adress=$_POST['email_adress'];
    $facebook=$_POST['facebook'];
    $adddate = date("d/m/Y");

    $photo = $_POST['photo'];

    $id=uniqid();


    $path = "vehicle_upload/$id.jpeg";
    $finalpath = "*********.$path;


    $sql1=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM _addvehicle WHERE 
 PlateNumber='$plate_number'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql1) > 0) {
            $result['success'] = "0";
            $result['message'] = "error";
            echo json_encode($result);
    }else{

        $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT IGNORE INTO 
_addvehicle(PlateNumber, Vin, Make, Model, Year, Displacement, FuelType, 
Transmission, Mileage, OwnerorCompany, HomeorCompanyAddress, ContactNumber, 
EmailAddress, FacebookID, AddDate, vehicleImage)VALUES('$plate_number','$vin','$car_make','$car_model','$car_year','$displacement','$fuel_type','$transmission','$mileage','$owner_name','$address','$phone_number','$email_adress','$facebook','$adddate','$finalpath')");

        if ($sql) {


                if (file_put_contents($path, base64_decode($photo))) {
                    $result['success'] = "1";
                    $result['message'] = "success";
                    echo json_encode($result);
                    //mysqli_close($connect);
                }

            }
    }



}
```

?>

Comment: The 406 error you get in return gives you a hint. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406, I would gues you haven't defined your post call correctly. Have you tried using something like postman to get the post request right first and the replicate the request in android?

Comment: @just_user, what's postman? I have added my PHP file codes on my post for better understanding.

Comment: You mean the link to the php file? Any php code is invisible if you open a link to it in the browser, by design. So any php code you would have to post in the question. https://www.getpostman.com/ Postman is a tool to test REST calls.

Comment: I'm no php expert, but you could add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the beginning of the file to display any errors received on the php side.

Comment: And you have two if statements `if ($sql` and `if (file`, if you don't enter any of those the server wont send you any response at all.

Comment: @just_user the thing is, I have another page in my app that has pretty much the same codes albeit with different values and they seem to work fine. Now I am stuck with the question between a code problem or a server side problem.

Answer (score 0):

In POST request you need to send parameters like an empty Hashmap i.e
{"":""} or you need to try https instead of http.